# Stanford POS tagger behaviour different from demo and Python

Tags: python, nltk, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I downloaded the full version of the Stanford POS Tagger from this link: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml#Download

However when I try to use it in my program in this way

```
 tokenized_text=nltk.word_tokenize(text)
 st = StanfordPOSTagger(path_pos_models,path_to_jar=path_pos_jar)
 POStagged_text = st.tag(tokenized_text)
```

it doesn't work like the one in the demo here:
http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process
. For example if I write:
"WHAT TIME THE AIR ARRIVE AT DESTINATION", 
in the demo ARRIVE is tagged as VBP while in my program is tagged as NNP.
Can someone please explain me why?

Comment: Apparently, they use a better trained PoS-tagger model in the demo than what they provide for download.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, there are several trained models bundled in the download. Maybe you are using a different one.